# Cannot pass a object to a controller method with popup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup

From an ajax call I get some data which I want to pass to another window in a button click. I receive the data successfully but when that data is passed, in controller methods parameter is receiving the value as null.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSalesInAmount').click(function () {
            var data = {
                toDate: $('#todatepicker').val(),
                fromDate: $('#fromdatepicker').val(),
                customerId: $('#CustomerId').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '/Reports/SalesInAmount' + '?toDate=' + data.toDate + '&fromDate=' + data.fromDate + '&customerId=' + data.customerId,
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {                       
                    window.open("/Reports/SalesInAmountView" + '?salesInAmount=' + data, 'SalesInAmountViewWindow', "features");// the data is not received by controllers method
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

in controller

```
 public ActionResult SalesInAmountView(SalesInAmount salesInAmount) // parameter value is null
    {
        return View();
    }
```

the model

```
   public class SalesInAmount
{
    public DateTime SalesDt { get; set; }
    public int SalesSl { get; set; }
    public int CustomerSupplyId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerSupplyNm { get; set; }
    public double TotalSalesByCustomer { get; set; }
    public double TotalDiscount { get; set; }
    public double TotalVat { get; set; }
    public double TotalSales { get; set; }
    public List<SalesInAmount> List { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `data` is a complex object (you cannot pass that in a query string) - it need to be `?toDate=' + data.toDate + '&fromDate=' + data.fromDate + ...`

Comment: do i need to make a ajax post call to pass the data?

Comment: Not for your `window.open()`. But you need to pass each name/value pair as a query string (just as you did in the `url:` option of the ajax call)

Comment: In addition, you do not need to add both the query string values to the url, and add the `data` option (you actually sending 2 lots of data in your ajax call.

Comment: yeah, you are write the cause of this behavior is it is a complex object. the data contains a list. that's why. can you give a solution?

Comment: See my first comment - `window.open("/Reports/SalesInAmountView" + '?toDate=' + data.toDate + '&fromDate=' + data.fromDate + '&customerId=' + data.customerId, ....)`

Comment: but the list parameter is receiving null like that

Comment: What list parameter?

Comment: the model SalesInAmount has a property named salesInAmounts which is a list type

Comment: Where in the question is there anything about that? We don't even know what that property is or what its a collection of, or how your passing the collection!

Comment: sorry about that. question updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

Simplify Your Data Set ,

```
 var Param1= $('#ID').val();
 var Data = JSON.stringify({ Data1 : Param1, . . });
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Action_Name", "Controller_Name")',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                data: Data,               
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    });

                }, error: function (request, status, error) {

                }
            });

        }
```

Controller

```
 public JsonResult Action_Name(string Data1 , . . )
        {

            return Json(Some_Json);
        }
```

**Note : this Controller Return Json Result , It depends on requirement .**

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the javascript object before pass as the parameter , JSON.stringify() is the function in javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSalesInAmount').click(function () {
        var data = {
            toDate: $('#todatepicker').val(),
            fromDate: $('#fromdatepicker').val(),
            customerId: $('#CustomerId').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: '/Reports/SalesInAmount',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (data) {                       
                window.open("/Reports/SalesInAmountView" + '?salesInAmount=' + data, 'SalesInAmountViewWindow', "features");// the data is not received by controllers method
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Make sure you have given same name of variable as you modal class SalesInAmount.

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult SalesInAmountView(SalesInAmount salesInAmount) // parameter value is null
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: still receiving the null value

Comment: Wrong - its a GET, which does not have a body - and OP's issue is with the `window.open()`, not the ajax call

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your comment, i have changed my answer

Comment: You need to remove the `data: JSON.stringify(data),` - its just `data: data,` as per OP's code, or it can be omitted altogether since its already being added in the `url:` option

Comment: I think it requires to data: JSON.stringify(data) for pass model from ajax request.

Comment: No it does not (and if you use `JSON.stringify()` you also need to set `contentType: 'application/json'` in order for it to work with the `DefautModelBinder`. But its a GET, which has no body so that would be pointless and will not work